# Convert percentage columns with % into numeric in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a small dataset as follows:

```
   id  price month_pct year_pct
0   1   1.85    -2.63%   -5.13%
1   2   2.42     0.00%    0.83%
2   3   1.81     0.00%   -0.55%
3   4   4.37    -2.89%   -5.62%
4   5   1.86     0.00%   -7.92%
5   6   1.78    -1.11%  -15.24%
```

I would like to convert `month_pct` and `year_pct` (which are factor type) into numeric then multiply by `100`.

How could I do that in R? Thanks.

```
   id  price month_pct year_pct
0   1   1.85    -2.63   -5.13
1   2   2.42     0.00    0.83
2   3   1.81     0.00   -0.55
3   4   4.37    -2.89   -5.62
4   5   1.86     0.00   -7.92
5   6   1.78    -1.11  -15.24
```

Code for reference:

```
df$month_pct <- as.numeric(sub("%", "", df$month_pct))/100
```

Comment: What is the problem in the code that you have? If you want to do this for multiple columns you can use `lapply`

Comment: You mean with `cols = c('month_pct', 'year_pct'); df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], as.numeric(sub("%", "")))`?

Comment: Yes, `df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) as.numeric(sub("%", "", x)) * 100)`

Comment: @RonakShah since everything is vectorized, no need to use `lapply`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, no bother to multiply by `100` after sub `%`.

Comment: @Onyambu I would prefer not to convert dataframe to matrix.

Comment: @RonakShah why not? Only the specific part that needs to be manipulated. Well then you could unlist it into one vector

Comment: @Onyambu No specific reason. I usually like to keep data in their original form. It also applies to not converting `data.table` to data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st solution: you can use `parse_number` from `readr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(month_pct:year_pct, ~readr::parse_number(.x) * 100))


#  id price month_pct year_pct
#1  1  1.85      -263     -513
#2  2  2.42         0       83
#3  3  1.81         0      -55
#4  4  4.37      -289     -562
#5  5  1.86         0     -792
#6  6  1.78      -111    -1524
```

2rd solution:

```
cols = c('month_pct', 'year_pct')
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) as.numeric(sub('%', '', x)) * 100)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tochange <- endsWith(names(df),"pct")
df[tochange] = as.numeric(sub("%", "", as.matrix(df[tochange]))) * 100

 df
  id price month_pct year_pct
0  1  1.85      -263     -513
1  2  2.42         0       83
2  3  1.81         0      -55
3  4  4.37      -289     -562
4  5  1.86         0     -792
5  6  1.78      -111    -1524
```